# Compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} (\sqrt{n^2-1^2} +\sqrt{n^2-2^2} + \sqrt{n^2-3^2} + \cdots + \sqrt{n^2-(n-1)^2}+0)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Show

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} (\sqrt{n^2-1^2} +\sqrt{n^2-2^2} + \sqrt{n^2-3^2} +\cdots  + \sqrt{n^2-(n-1)^2}+0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Unfortunately I'm not even sure where to start this one.
Maybe turn it into an integral somehow? The result suggests maybe something with an arctan?

Comment: Hint: Riemann sums

Comment: Hint: approximate the unit circle's area in the positive quadrant with a sum of rectangle areas.

Comment: What If you take n^2 out from all square root terms and expand all  using binomial theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

[Yup it turns into an integral but it's not arctan. The sigma transformation to an integral and the 1/n term into the limits.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhCfb.jpg)
Also take the x as "r/n"

Comment: Please use MathJax to write equations. Don't post links to pictures.